# why 'function(){}()' throw a error ? but '!function(){}()' not?

Tags: javascript

when I was writing code as below，it throw a error。

`function(){}()`

If I add '!' ,it will not .why?I'm confused。

`!function(){}()`

Comment: what's the extra parenthesis for?

Comment: Because the first is a *function declaration* without the mandatory name, the second is a *function expression* where the name is optional.